# Java Graphics - Keeping track of shapes

Tags: java, swing, graphics, shapes

So I am making an application and I want to keep track of the shapes added to the screen. I have the following code so far, but when a circle is added it cannot be moved/changed. Ideally, I'd want something like shift-click to move it around/highlight it.

I'm also wondering how I could make it so that you can drag a line from one circle to another. I don't know if I'm using the wrong tools for the job here but any help would be appreciated.

```
import javax.swing.*;
import java.awt.*;
import java.awt.event.*;

public class MappingApp extends JFrame implements MouseListener { 

  private int x=50;   // leftmost pixel in circle has this x-coordinate
  private int y=50;   // topmost  pixel in circle has this y-coordinate

  public MappingApp() {
    setSize(800,800);
    setLocation(100,100);
    addMouseListener(this); 
    setVisible(true);
  }

  // paint is called automatically when program begins, when window is
  //   refreshed and  when repaint() is invoked 
  public void paint(Graphics g) {
    g.setColor(Color.yellow);
    g.fillOval(x,y,100,100);

}

  // The next 4 methods must be defined, but you won't use them.
  public void mouseReleased(MouseEvent e ) { }
  public void mouseEntered(MouseEvent e)   { }
  public void mouseExited(MouseEvent e)    { }
  public void mousePressed(MouseEvent e)   { }

  public void mouseClicked(MouseEvent e) { 
    x = e.getX();   // x-coordinate of the mouse click
    y = e.getY();   // y-coordinate of the mouse click
    repaint();    //calls paint()
  }

  public static void main(String argv[]) {
    DrawCircle c = new DrawCircle();
  }
}
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Use java.awt.geom.* to create shapes, use fields to reference them and then use the graphics object to draw them.

for eg:

```
Ellipse2D.Float ellipse=new Ellipse2D.Float(50,50,100,100);

graphics.draw(ellipse);
```

Comment: graphics is pseudo. I'm referring to whatever graphics object you're using. The example you have uses 'g' as the reference. Try g.draw()

Comment: +1 for painting with Shapes. However, the Graphics class does not know how to paint Shapes. You need to use the `Graphics2D` class. Also you should use the `fill()` method. The draw() method just paints the outline of the Shape. See [Playing With Shapes](http://tips4java.wordpress.com/2013/05/13/playing-with-shapes/) for more information.

Answer (score 4):

1) See [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12933592/clicking-on-a-drawn-object/12934769#12934769) answer for clicking/selecting a drawn objects and [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14279893/java-own-components-visually-connecting-per-drag-and-drop/14280467#14280467) for creating lines via press, and drag of mouse.

2) You should not be overriding `JFrame` `paint(..)`.

Rather add `JPanel` to `JFrame` and override `paintComponent(Graphics g)` of `JPanel` not forgetting to call `super.paintComponent(g);` as first call in the overriden method:

```
@Override
protected void paintComponent(Graphics g) {
   super.paintComponent(g);

   g.setColor(Color.yellow);
   g.fillOval(x,y,100,100);

}
```

As per [`paintComponent(Graphics g)`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/javax/swing/JComponent.html#paintComponent%28java.awt.Graphics%29) docs:

> Further, if you do not invoker super's implementation you must honor
>   the opaque property, that is if this component is opaque, you must
>   completely fill in the background in a non-opaque color. If you do not
>   honor the opaque property you will likely see visual artifacts.

3) Dont call `setSize` on `JFrame` use correct `LayoutManager` and/or override `getPreferredSize` (usually done when drawing to `JPanel` so it may fit our Graphic content) and than call `pack()` on `JFrame` before setting it visible.

4) Have a read on [Concurrecny in Swing](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/concurrency/) especially [Event-Dispatch-Thread](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/concurrency/dispatch.html).

Comment: I just noticed you passed 20K!  Congrats., it is well deserved.  :)

Comment: +1 hehe thank you I feel like I might be able to say I know a bit about Swing :)!

Answer (score 0):

You are extending JFrame so you should consider calling super.paint(g); at the beginning of the overridden paint method.