# How do you determine if the mouse is point to a particular object?

Tags: java, swing

There is a question in this textbook I am reading:

" How would you determine if the mouse is pointing to a particular object _ball which is declared to be an Ellipse2D.Double in a subclass of JPanel. the MouseEvent object is referenced by the parameted named "e". "

I am confused as to what it means by "mouse is pointing" does that mean the mouse is being clicked on the _ball? if that is the case, wouldn't the answer be to implement the java.awt.event.MouseListener on the _ball object and use the java.awt.event.MouseEvent class somehow?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can define what it means.

It could mean "clicking" on the ball as you have suggested. Or it could mean "moving over" the ball.

Either way you would add a `MouseListener` to the panel. Then you either need to add your code to the `mousePressed()` or `mouseMoved()` event. When the event fires you would need to get the mouse point of the event and then use the `contains()` method of the ellipse to determine if you "clicked" or are "moving over" the ball.

Comment: when you say "add your code to the mousePressed() or mouseMoved() even" -- where are these methods located? in the JPanel? and when you say "add a MouseListener" does that mean implement MouseListener interface in the JPanel and create a private mouseListener class to handle the mouse point?

Comment: @user2533249, Read the Swing tutorial on [How to Write a Mouse Listener](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/events/mouselistener.html) for an example of using a MouseListener.

Comment: +1.... @user2533249 also see [this](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12933592/clicking-on-a-drawn-object/12934769#12934769) answer which demonstrates camickr's solution