# How do you create a clickable object in Java Swing?

Tags: java, swing, button, graphics, awt

[image]

how do you create a JButton with a particular shape? here I want the shape of a pen, ie I want it to be clickable only on the surface of the pen.
Thanks!

Comment: See [Creating a custom button in Java with JButton](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5751311/creating-a-custom-button-in-java-with-jbutton).  Good luck.  It will take a lot of effort.

Comment: Your "basic" question comes to basic "collision detection" - given a x/y position (ie mouse click), is the x/y position within the bounds of the pen.  The difficult part for you is trying to "map" the pen to something which can be easily compared to.  You "could" look at the pixels, if they are non-alpha, then you're probably within the pen or you could create a "mapping" shape (more difficult, but easy to deal with it) which defines the a "clickable" area - all of these have been asked and answered before, I suggest some additional research into the topics

Comment: Do you need it the component to be a `JButton` or is it enough if it is just a "clickable shape" (https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21355434/create-clickable-graphics-java)?

Comment: Following up on @MadProgrammer comment you would override the `contains(...)` method of the button to determine if the click occurred on a non transparent pixel.

Comment: d'accord merci pour vos réponses, !